# The value of second input type="number" cannot be exceed to the value of the first input type="number" maxlength="3"

Tags: html, asp-classic

This is the testing code, without using button, the second textbox will accept the number if the value is <= to the first textbox.

```
<html>
<body>

<input id="first" name="first" type="number" maxlength = "3">

<input id="second" name="second" type="number" maxlength = "3"      onblur="compare()" >


</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function compare()
{
 var firstNumber = document.getElementById("first").value;
 var secondNumber = document.getElementById("second").value;
 if(firstNumber >= secondNumber)
 {
  //nothing will do, continue to the 3rd textbox.
 }
 else
 {
 alert("The number you enter is larger than the first one.");
  //clear the value of the second textbox
 }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Is your title the error message you are getting, or is that what you trying to achieve?   Exactly what is the question?   P.S. that looks like pure html and no asp-classic/vbscript code.

Comment: sorry sir, my bad.., i will import this code to my asp file(complete code) if my concern resolve.

Comment: So what is your question?  Does the code not work as expected?

Comment: onkeypress and onblur ... I change the attributes from onkeypress to onblur.. thank you so much sir., problem solved .. also thanks to @user4261590.. Godbless..

Comment: sir, one last question., how can i auto clear the value of the second text box, if the value of the second textbox is greater than the first one.. @Dijkgraaf.

Comment: document.getElementById("second").value = "";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you are not getting any errors but you are looking to do a comparison on two inputs.

You are going to have to use javascript. You will need to store each input in a variable. Then you will need to write a function to compare the values of these variables and display an output.

For example:

```
<button type="button" onclick="compare()">Compare!</button>

<script>

function compare()
{
 var firstNumber = document.getElementById("first").value;
 var secondNumber = document.getElementById("second").value;
 if(firstNumber == secondNumber)
 {
  alert("The numbers are equal");
 }
 else if(firstNumber > secondNumber)
 {
  alert("The first number is larger");
 }
 else
 {
  alert("The second number is larger");
 }
}

</script>
```

Then you would put your own code in where the second number is larger based on what you want to happen.

Edit: Sorry if you wanted this in classic ASP. I'm sure you'll be able to translate it into it anyway.

Comment: sir. thank you for your answer but i need to have it without a button.. once the user enter a number to the 1st textbox, the second box will automatically compare it's value if it is less than or equal, if the value is greater than the value of the 1st,, there's an alert that notify the user that he/she can only enter a number that less than or equal to the 1st.

Comment: <html>
<body>

<input id="first" name="first" type="number" maxlength = "3" >

<input id="second" name="second" type="number" maxlength = "3" onkeypress="compare()" >


</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function compare()
{ var firstNumber = document.getElementById("first").value;
 var secondNumber = document.getElementById("second").value;
 if(firstNumber == secondNumber)
 { alert("The numbers are equal");
 }
 else if(firstNumber > secondNumber)
 {  alert("The first number is larger");
 }
 else
 {
  alert("The second number is larger");
 }
}
</script>

Comment: @rabal  If you have a clarification to your question please use the edit link under the question and add it to that.  Posting it in comments makes it hard to read and might be missed by people.  Also you can use a onchange on each input to call the function rather than the button if that is what you need

Comment: @Dijkgraaf please checked the edited codes. thanks

Comment: @rabal You won't be able to compare the 2 numbers when the number is entered into the first box as it is likely there will be nothing in the second to compare it with. I don't know about `onblur` but I think you will want to use `onchange=compare()` on the second box. This is bad design though as while the user is typing, the size of the value is changing.